# Problems with insertion into an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
vm.categorias = function () {
  ConectaVagas('get', 'categorias').then(function (val) {
      vm.categorias = val;
      for (var a = 0; a < vm.categorias.length; a++) {
          console.log(a); // Here returns 0,1,2,3 ( number with categories )
          ConectaVagas('get', 'subcategoria', vm.categorias[a].id_categoria).then(function (val) { // List the subcategories related the categorie in loopfor
              vm.subAplicar = val;
              console.log(a); // Here returns the number 4 but i want returns 0, 1, 2, 3 and i do the insertion in arrayNova
              vm.categoria[a].arrayNova = vm.subAplicar;
          });
      }
  });
}
```

I need to insert into the object `vm.category [a]` an array (`arrayNova`) with all subcategories, but I am not following :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose in a new function the second call to ConnectVagas. Your variable a always prints to 4, because in javascript variables have a function scope. In order to correct this, create an anonymous function with parameters the current_item and a, so the value of a will not get overwritten because it creates a new function scope.

```
vm.categorias = function() {
  ConectaVagas('get', 'categorias').then(function(val) {
    vm.categorias = val;
    for (var a = 0; a < vm.categorias.length; a++) {
      console.log(a); // Here returns 0,1,2,3 ( number with categories )
      var categorias_item = vm.categorias[a].id_categoria
      (function(categorias_item, a) {
        ConectaVagas('get', 'subcategoria', categorias_item.id_categoria).then(function(val) { // List the subcategories related the categorie in loopfor
          vm.subAplicar = val;
          console.log(a); // Here returns the number 4 but i want returns 0, 1, 2, 3 and i do the insertion in arrayNova
          categorias_item.arrayNova = vm.subAplicar;
        });
      })(categorias_item, a);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice, tnx! Right :)